# What's the equation for the discount in below case?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, math, user-interface

I want to form the equation for the discount...I have the following case:

```
net total = sale rate - discount + tax amount.
here.
 tax amount = tax% * (sale rate - discount)
```

In my form I allow the user to change the net total to adjust like whole amount that means if net total comes 8010,user can adjust it as 8000. So the adjusted amount should deduct from discount only...but the sale rate and tax% should not change...so how to form the equation to find the discount...is there anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a Math question ?

Comment: Yes..I've this case in my form

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the whole equation as

```
net_total = (sale_rate - discount)*(1.0 + tax%)
```

which makes it more obvious that

```
discount = sale_rate - whatever_the user_inputs/(1.0 + tax%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round net total. But for rounding you have to write your own logic, if you want me to write it for you i can